# Why does Android Volley fail to retrieve data on Android Q?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm using Volley 1.1.1 to retrieve some JSON data via URL.

My example is taken from official Android docs : [Send a simple request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) -- though it is slightly altered to make it a bit simpler (see code below).

**Manifest Permissions**

I've added the proper permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Tested Successfully On Other Android Versions**

I've tested and run this example and it runs successfully on :

- Android 7 (Nougat)
- Android 8.1 (Oreo)

**Connectivity Test**

I can retrieve the data via browser (using URL shown in code below) on the device running Android Q.

**Kotlin Code**

I Log various things along the way so I can tell how far it gets.

```
importSiteKeysButton!!.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "import button clicked!")

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(it.context)
    val url = "http://raddev.us/allsitekeys.json"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
           Request.Method.GET, url,
           Response.Listener<String> { response ->

              Log.d("MainActivity", "URL returned...")
              Log.d("MainActivity","Response is: ${response}")
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { 
            Log.d("MainActivity", "That didn't work!")})

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

On Nougat and Oreo I see the expected success result:

```
12-12 11:42:24.299  3273  3273 D MainActivity: import button clicked!
12-12 11:42:24.776  3273  3273 D MainActivity: URL returned...
12-12 11:42:24.776  3273  3273 D MainActivity: Response is: [{"HasSpecialChars":false,"HasUpperCase":false,"Key":"c3VwZXJzaXRl","MaxLength":0},{"HasSpecialChars":false,"HasUpperCase":false,"Key":"dGhyZWU=","MaxLength":0},{"HasSpecialChars":false,"HasUpperCase":false,"Key":"c2Vjb25kU2l0ZQ==","MaxLength":0},{"HasSpecialChars":false,"HasUpperCase":false,"Key":"eWV0QW5vdGhlcg==","MaxLength":0},{"MaxLength":0,"HasSpecialChars":false,"HasUpperCase":false,"Key":"IUAjJCVeJiooKXt9"}]
```

However, on Android Q I get the error response every time:

```
12-12 11:44:32.299  3273  3273 D MainActivity: import button clicked!
12-12 11:44:33.226  3273  3273 D MainActivity: That didn't work!
```

Is there some special permission I am missing or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

can you try add usesClearTextTraffic=true in manifest?

This might happen because, since Android Pie, we are recommended to use secure network traffic so the default value for usesClearTextTraffic is false since Android Pie

You can read [this](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6) article to read more about it

Comment: Thanks I will try this out as soon as I can and set this to answer if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Since you put me on the correct path I was able to use my httpS site to successfully retrieve my JSON file.  once I used the secure URL (https:// fake/allSiteKeys.json) it worked fine on Android Q.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Also wanted to confirm that adding the android:usesCleartextTraffic option to manifest (when using http URL) does resolve this issue also.  Just tested it on Android Q and it worked fine.